# Xcode Interface Builder broken line rendering at 100% zoom

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

When viewing layouts at 100% zoom, borders have a strange diagonal cutoff where they no longer render:

[image: Screenshot at 100%]

This doesn't occur at any other zoom level:

[image: Screenshot at 110%]

I know the simulator has an "Optimize Rendering for Window Scale" setting, is there an equivalent for interface builder?

Comment: This does not occur to me with Xcode 9.3. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: 9.2.  I wasn't aware there was a new stable out, seems the app store has neglected to inform me.  I'm updating currently, I'll report back.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: It does still occur in 9.3.  I think I'm looking at an issue with my monitor, if I place the window on a different monitor, the issue is resolved.

Comment: Is only one of your monitors retina? That can easily cause this scaling issue.

Comment: Good guess!  I just haven't had a chance to look into why it would be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by utilizing incorrect hardware to connect with the monitor.  Being a 4k monitor, my macbook was forcing a higher resolution.